# Showing $\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)^n = -1$ implies $z$ is real

Tags: complex-numbers

I have shown the following identity: $$ \frac{1+e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}} = \frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) $$ And I now need to use this to show that the the equation: $$ \left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)^n = -1$$ has $\Im(z) = 0$.

I'm not sure where to get started on this, I have found a way to do it by conjugating the 2nd equation on both sides and showing that z is equal to its own conjugate, however this does not use the original identity, and I'd really like to see how it follows from that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you conjugate the first fraction you get $(1+u^{-1})/(1-u^{-1})=-(1+u)/(1-u)$ (where $u=e^{i\theta}$), which means the number is purely imaginary, so your first identity is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your identity  as  $$\frac{1+e^{i2t}}{1-e^{2it}}=\frac{1+\cos2t+i\sin2t}{1-\cos2t-i\sin2t}=\frac{2\cos^2t+i2\sin t\cos t}{2\sin^2t-i2\sin t\cos t}$$

$$=\frac{2\cos t(\cos t+i\sin t)}{-2i\sin t(i\sin t+\cos t)}=i\cot t$$

Now using [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications) , $$\frac{z+i}{z-i}=(-1)^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{(2r+1)i\pi}n}$$ where $0\le r<n$

Applying [componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo), $$\frac z{-i}=\frac{e^{\frac{(2r+1)i\pi}n}+1}{e^{\frac{(2r+1)i\pi}n}-1}=i \cot \frac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n}$$

$$\implies z= \cot \frac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n}$$

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow? How does this relate to the original identity? Thanks

Comment: @Wooster, can you follow it now?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think you missed sign somewhere in identity with $\cot$.

Comment: @Kaster, please have a look into the edited version

Comment: @labbhattacharjee looks good to me.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes this is great, thanks

Comment: @Wooster, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac {1+e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}} = -\frac {e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}} = -\frac {2\cos \frac \theta 2}{2i \sin \frac \theta 2} = -\frac 1i \cot \frac \theta 2 = i \cot \frac \theta 2
$$
You can recheck it [here](http://bit.ly/18DyonM).

As for the second part
$$
\left ( \frac {z+i}{z-i}\right )^n = -1 \\
\frac {z+i}{z-i} = e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n} \\
z + i = (z-i) e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n} \\
z \left ( 1-e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}\right) = -i \left ( 1+e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}\right) \\
z = -i\ \left ( \frac {1+e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}}{1-e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}} \right )
$$
Based on first result
$$
\frac {1+e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}}{1-e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi i}n}} = i \cot \frac {(2k+1)\pi}{2n}
$$
so
$$
z = -i^2 \cot \frac {(2k+1)\pi}{2n} = \cot \frac {(2k+1)\pi}{2n}
$$
which is real, i.e. $\Im(z) = 0$.